# Accessing request headers with Zapier Webhook triggers

Tags: http, security, http-headers, webhooks, zapier

Is there a way to retrieve HTTP Headers when using Zapier Webhook triggers? With `Catch Hook` and `Catch Raw Hook` triggers the headers doesn't seem to be available in later steps (even using a Code step).

For example with something like:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H 'x-webhook-signature: abc123!'
     POST -d '{"secret": "I am a banana"}'
     https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/123/abc/
```

How to read the value of `x-webhook-signature` value in a Zapier in or after a Webhook trigger?

This is especially important for us as the headers contains authentication information without which we cannot verify the authenticity nor the identity of the sender. It's a great security issue.

Comment: Can you just put `x-webhook-signature` as a field in the payload?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the header cannot be moved in another part of the request.

Comment: Well, it seems Zapier doesn't expose HTTP headers in Webhook. I just made a Webhook in my Zapier account and... no matter what I do, the header data cannot be retrieved. Maybe you need to create a Proxy server and move header to payload there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but this isn't something we currently support in our webhooks app. If the proxy server isn't an option, it might be possible to write a custom [CLI](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli) app to catch your hooks. It has access to the incoming header and could copy that information into the body. The tricky part of that is that you no longer have the benefit of a single URL to throw hooks at - each zaps broadcasts its url when it's turned on. Success would depend on being able to capture that broadcast somewhere and adjust your data accordingly.

Again, sorry this isn't possible now. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks David, I'll take a look into that. Any chance you will add a this as a new feature to the Zapier Webhook trigger in the (near) future?

Comment: Yes indeed! I've made a note about it in or internal feature tracker. We'll probably comment here if it ever gets made (normally we take an email, but this question works fine)

Comment: If you move a payload signature from header to the payload - the signature will change.

Answer (score 0):

Premium Zapier accounts have `Catch Raw Hook` Trigger. In there you can read headers.

https://zapier.com/blog/updates/1113/webhooks-catch-raw-hooks